# My laptop boots into BIOS after I installed Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04

I recently bought a ASUS laptop and Windows 10 was pre-installed in it.  So I installed Ubuntu and completely erased Windows 10. But after installing Ubuntu my laptop only boots into BIOS . I checked the boot menu there is no option to boot from HDD.

Comment: Can you access Ubuntu manually?

Comment: No I can't. Only thing I can do is use it from USB drive.

Comment: Do you have a recovery parition or a DVD/USB to repair BIOS from ASUS?

Comment: I would install it again, just to make sure if the problem persists. Did you installed just once?

Comment: No I don't have I completely erased everything from the HDD

Comment: I tried to install again but had no luck.

Comment: It 'd be best to look/google for a way to repair/update BIOS on your computer. A friend with the same model and a recovery partition cloner like Macrium Reflect could help.
P.S. Erase recovery partition  :(

Comment: When starting your computer if you press Esc or F12 to enter on boot menu what are the options?

Comment: I don't need to press anything it just opens BIOS.

Comment: Is it because of UEFI. Because when was installing it me a  message " Force UEFI Installation? This machines's firmware has started this installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there maybe existing operating systems already installed using BIOS compatibility mode, If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode,it might be difficult to reboot into any BIOS-mode operating system."

Comment: @Jay , I have a HP laptop and, unfortunatelly, I ALWAYS have to enter on the boot options to access ubuntu. Try entering on asus ubuntu options. I think you have to type  at startup Esc or F12

Comment: It only opens up BIOS no matter what button I press.  No boot menu or anything else.

Comment: Since you don't have any files you want at your disk, try again with the live cd and choose try (instead of install) then install `gparted`, choose your hard disk from `GParted`-> `Devices` and recreate a `gpt` partition table from `Device`-> `Create Partition Table`. Then try the  UEFI installation again.

Comment: What model Asus? And you should be able to install in BIOS/CSM or UEFI boot mode, but then need to have UEFI set to boot in that mode. Partitioning in Advance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu, then use Something Else: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the UEFI.  Set it to Bios Legacy mode.  I read the following in a comment concerning Asus accepting only Windows UEFI signatures. For this question [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786614/boot-doesnt-proceed-on-my-laptop-but-do-on-other-machines)

*Windows is the culprit, as usual !! Boot into UEFI menu, disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Boot or something like that. Every modern operating system is using a secure signature (key) to tell UEFI it is a genuine operating system (not malware fakes). For some weird reason (Windows motherlover) the manufacturer (ASUS) has set the G551V UEFI to accept only Windows signatures. – ipse lute Jun 13 at 21:49*

Comment: Wow! Don't take it too serious! Asus is making many many laptop models! I personally owned like 3 models and i never had any problems with any of them. That secure signature key may affect ONLY laptops that have Windows preinstalled. A 'special gift' for Windows lovers. It's like gsm-carrier locked phones. You get a Microsoft discount if you 'promise' never to uninstall Windows. Magnificent, isn't it? They must have got that idea from Nokia.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging and repluggin your hard drive.

Alternatively, boot from the install media with the drive plugged in.  If it's there, re-install Ubuntu.