# Boot doesn't proceed on my laptop, but do on other machines

Tags: boot, system-installation

This is my first time Ubuntu experience and I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop.

All of the instructions suggested [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) and [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), followed step by step.

I managed to reach Ubuntu installation menu and **Try Ubuntu without installation** option was selected. At the next step, that splash-like page containing Ubuntu logo in a purple-colored background appeared. **But, the boot process doesn't continue any more from this step.** I tried several times using USB or DVD and the results were the same.

The health of downloaded .iso file was checked according to Ubuntu help page (HowToMD5SUM). The result showed that the downloaded file was correct (hash code checking).

Besides, two other laptops were tried, Asus S550C and Asus N56JR and the results were absolutely successful.

So, I concluded that my machine is making trouble. It is an Asus G551V. Please note that this machine currently runs Windows 10 without problems and many apps are installed on it well.

This is so frustrating, I can not even try Ubuntu. **Can anybody please help me to solve this?**

Comment: Windows is the culprit, as usual !! Boot into UEFI menu, disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Boot or something like that. Every modern operating system is using a secure signature (key) to tell UEFI it is a genuine operating system (not malware fakes). For some weird reason (Windows motherlover) the manufacturer (ASUS) has set the G551V UEFI to accept only Windows signatures.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check your BIOS, and see if it is set to boot in UEFI mode.

You may need to change it to Legacy mode to be able to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I actually changed my pc to BIOS from UEFI following everyone's advice before I encountered this problem. Turned out I had to change back to UEFI to install it.